# How to load image in image control and templatebinding using control template?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have a simple form where i have added a image control .Now i want to load image from local directory. I want to use templatebinding .How can i use image control through templatebinding ? Please give me suggesstion.

Answer (score 1):

this may work for you

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Control Tag="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Sunset.jpg">
        <Control.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Control.Template>
    </Control>
</Page>
```

Comment: Its working fine but i want load image using relative path (../Images/Flower2.jpg).I am writing below code but its not loading the image .Image folder location is Myproject bin folder                                          <Control Tag="../Images/Flower2.jpg" >
   <Control.Template>                                                  <StackPanel>
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
     </StackPanel>
   </Control.Template>
</Control>  please help how it can be possible ?